# JDBC error while connecting java with Oracle 18c

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I am getting below error when I am connecting Oracle 18c database with java.
The command I am using.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@100.100.209.28:1521:PDB1","cmiapps","WEXXXX##");
```

Error I am getting.

```
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

When I am running below query I am getting `PDB1` as service name.

```
select name from dba_services;
```

Could you please help me on the same?

Comment: Do you know what a SID is and why the driver thinks you have provided one?

Comment: SID is PDB1. and I have queried in sqldeveloper using table dba_services.

Comment: is that the correct query to know SID name?

Comment: The URL format when using a service name is different. The format you are using has been deprecated with Oracle 10. See the example "Thin style service name" [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-EF07727C-50AB-4DCE-8EDC-57F0927FF61A)

Comment: `100.100.209.28:1521/PDB1` as @a_horse_with_no_name informed

Comment: @JoopEggen when I did above changes this error is coming. "Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor"

Comment: It is not `.../PDB1.pvtsub1.imcm..` I hope...

Comment: @OnkarTiwari - what is the relevance of the 'connection details' image? If that works for whatever client that is then use the same full service name that does? I can't remember off-hand if it is used here but what is your `db_domain` parameter set to - `pvtsub1.imcm...`? Also see what `lsnrctl services` on the DB server reports as the name(s) it will recognise.

Comment: you can't use a SID to connect to a PDB, you have to use it's Service name

Comment: thank you so much. I can connect successfully. many thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment by @thatjeffsmith , you can not use `SID` to connect with `PDB` database. you will have to use `service name` for the same.

Comment: How can we know the service name?

Comment: select value from v$parameter where name='service_names';